# Setting custom path to php.ini (not in Apache)

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn Symfony that "requires" using php in the command line / terminal for some tasks.

I like to store my `php.ini` in the `/apache2/conf` directory, to have all the server configs at one place (and not having to deal with Windows' UAC everytime I change something). In Apache, it's no problem to set the default php.ini location via

```
PHPIniDir "C:/apache2/conf"
```

However, when running php from the terminal - not through the apache server - it looks for the file in the C:\Windows directory by default, although there's none there:

```
C:\>php -i
...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
...
```

Of course, I can bypass this by using the `php -c C:\apache2\conf ...` everytime I use it but I'd prefer a more easy and permanent solution.

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can override php.ini values via .htaccess and httpd.conf. Rather than maintain two seperate .ini files, you could have one global one, and then a few overrides in your Apache .conf files.

Comment: @profitphp I agree with the sentiment of your comment but don't see how using Linux would change anything in this case.

Comment: Marc, I don't want to have two separate .ini files, that is exactly the point. But my problem was with CLI, so neither .htaccess or httpd.conf would help. Fixed now, thanks anyway!

Comment: profitphp, I tried it many times, with quite a few distributions and it never got close to my heart. Maybe next time :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

> php.ini is searched in these locations (in order):
>
> - SAPI module specific location (PHPIniDir directive in Apache 2, -c command line option in CGI and CLI, php_ini parameter in NSAPI, PHP_INI_PATH environment variable in THTTPD)
> - The PHPRC environment variable. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was checked after the registry key mentioned below.
> - As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in order: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z], [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in these keys, then the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).
> - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).
> - Current working directory (except CLI)
> - The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP (otherwise in Windows)
> - Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt) (for Windows), or --with-config-file-path compile time option

In addition as of PHP 5.3, you can use per-directory .ini files. See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: How silly of me, I couldn't find it with Google and didn't think of checking the manual... I've used the environment variable and works perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\5\IniFilePath -> (your path)