# php date function works on local host but not on xampp server?

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I have xamp installed on local host on a windows xp pc and i have a linux server with xamp .

I have a development page on my local server and a production page on the remote linux server. 
The 2 pages are identical however on the linux server i do not get any value for for the date function . It seems as the date function is not working on the linux server . (While it works localy without a glich)

Unable to find any relevant information on google i wander if anybody ever had a similar issue or has any idea why dose this happen any tip would be most appreciated?

Comment: You are using xampp on a production system? That's a **very bad idea**.

Comment: Does ANY php function work on the production machine?

Comment: define "not working"! Do you get errors? Is it showing a wrong time if you echo the output of a date() call?

Comment: ok thanks for your answers , first why is it a bad idea tu use xampp on production server , and also all other used php functions work , it just dose not print any value

Comment: XAMPP is intended for developers to run a local web server. It probably has lots of security holes (and won't be auto updated if new exploits are found).

Comment: so what should i use instead of xampp

Comment: +1 for the previous comments about xamp. But to solve your current issue, I guess you may have a look at the php.ini file(s) and search for time.zone, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6434564/461212)

Comment: I guess you have not used PHP tags properly. windows allows <? but linux only allows <?php

Comment: @Gunnit: Using XAMPP as production server IS NOT a bad idea, if you have it configured properly (securely). Other thing that it is really hard do achieve it, but it is not impossible. BTW: there are different kind of descriptions for "production server". For example, one of my project uses XAMPP that way, but it is 100% internal, intranet project. Especially for projects like this, used by limited number of users, not publicly available, I don't see XAMPP as bad idea for production server. But for public websites with large number of users I would agree and think twice before using it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Using XAMPP as production server IS NOT a bad idea, by definition. Some projects are cool with this combination (see my previous comment). And by the way. Can you define what in your opinion is so bad about using XAMPP as production server? XAMPP itself isn't a ready solution. It is a package containing Apache, PHP, MySQL etc. Are you so sure, that installing them separately will rise your security? If you're a bad admin, both XAMPP other packages and installing by-hand, will always be bad idea for production server. It is just a matter of knowledge, configuration and security.