# "phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings..."

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, ini

While running a php installation script for Blue.box (front end to FreeSwitch PBX), I get this error about a timezone failure.

Then I start digging.  I'm not sure what is going on at this point.  But here is what I have:

I created an info.php file in my public_html directory that contains a single line:

And I get this error and output

> Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
>   'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /home/0default/public_html/info.php on line
>   1

```
date/time

     support    enabled
    "Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
    Timezone Database   internal
    Default timezone    America/New_York

    Directive   Local Value Master Value
    date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
    date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
    date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
    date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
    date.timezone   America/New_York    America/New_York
```

I created a file /etc/php.d/timezone.ini with the following:

```
[root@mercury php.d]# cat timezone.ini
; default time zone
date.timezone='America/New_York'
[root@mercury php.d]#
```

I'm able to change timezone to America/Los_Angeles (for example), and after apache reboot the "date.timezone" field changes correctly.

But I still get the error.

Any ideas?

--- Additional note ---

If I change the /etc/php.d/timezone.ini file:

```
[root@mercury php.d]# cat timezone.ini
; default time zone
date.timezone='America/Los_Angeles'
```

I can cause a change to the info.php output:

date

Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /home/0default/public_html/info.php on line 1

```
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    America/New_York

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   America/Los_Angeles America/Los_Angeles
```

--- Additional note ---

For those who are learning (as I am), several .ini files are loaded.  In the info.php output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /home/0default/etc/php5/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/gd.ini, /etc/php.d/imap.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/odbc.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_pgsql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/pgsql.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/snmp.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/timezone.ini, /etc/php.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlrpc.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

The first one loaded is /etc/php.ini, then the "loaded configuration file", then the "scan this dir" files.

So for example, one should be able to create a number of php web sites in different default timezones.  Set the master default in /etc/php.ini, then allow each of the web sites to have a different time zone as identified in the "loaded..." section.  Then, if one is concerned about any overrides, the master can again override with the /etc/php.d files.

I've tried changing the "date.timezone" in each of the three locations, and successfully change the date.timezone as displayed by the info.php... but it does not modify the "Default timezone" value, which is the value that is causing the error.

Another note, the .php script that I am running is actually Blue.box, a front end to FreeSwitch.  So... I am hesitant in changing that .php script.

Comment: did you change the right php.ini? There's usually two: CLI and SAPI, and you might have changed the wrong one. `phpinfo()` in the script that's causing the warning will tell you which .ini files were used.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I can only say yes based on the fact that I get the new information when I reload the info.php file. (I added that to the original post)

Comment: Just a guess, but try using double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`), or removing the quotes alltogether.

Comment: Also - are you running under Apache?  Perhaps [this applies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6434564/634824).

Answer (score 11):

You have 2 options:

1. Call this function [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before using any date functions. E.g. `date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");`.
2. Edit the php.ini file usually located at `/usr/local/php/php.ini` and change the [date.timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) entry. Here is the [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: Hi, the php.ini option is what I tried, in /etc/php.ini

Comment: I've since tried the date_default_timezone_set() option in the info.php script, it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkSatterfield After editing php.ini, you will have to restart apache.

Comment: Thanks @MikePurcell.  I did restart, and even tried to reboot.  No love.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm having the same issue on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by find which php.ini your server is using.
First, you should make a page show phpinfo(), and you visit the page, you can see the normal infomation; 
Second, find "Loaded Configuration File" in the page, you should see what php.ini file your server is using. like:"/etc/php.ini";
Third, you edit the certain file in your server, like: date.timezone="Asia/Shanghai" then restart the server. 
Done. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had update php.ini in two places. One was `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. You have to restart your apache and then it should work. Hope this helps!!!